# grouped options select with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have json object for which i am trying to write a grouped_options using jquery.
My json object looks like this

```
data = {"01 CONSULT":[["1b Rules","40"]],"02 DEVELOPMENT":[],"03 QUALITY":[],"05 MARKETING":[["5e Research","66"]],"06 MISCELLANEOUS":[["6a Training","69"],["6b Meetings","70"]}
```

My dropdown should look like this :

```
 **01 CONSULT**
   1b Rules
 **02 DEVELOPMENT**
 **03 QUALITY**
 **05 MARKETING**
   5e Research
 **06 MISCELLANEOUS**
   6a Training
   6b Meetings
```

My code currently looks like this. I am not able to get the parent values in the dropdown as I am struggling to write the jquery with grouped_options.

```
  function change(data){
    $("#task_id").empty();
      for(var y in data){
        $("#task_id").append(
        $("<option></option>").attr("value", y).text(data[y]).appendTo("optgroup");
  );
```

}
}

Any help would be appreciated..Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code doesn't append any optgroup elements. Maybe you can do something like this:

```js
data = {"01 CONSULT":[["1b Rules","40"]],"02 DEVELOPMENT":[],"03 QUALITY":[],"05 MARKETING":[["5e Research","66"]],"06 MISCELLANEOUS":[["6a Training","69"],["6b Meetings","70"]]}

function change(data){
  var slct = $("#task_id")
  slct.empty()
  
  Object.keys(data).forEach(function(og) {                 // for each data key
    var optgroup = $("<optgroup></optgroup>", {label: og}) // create optgroup element
    data[og].forEach(function(opt) {                       // for each option
      $("<option></option>", {                             // create option element
        value: opt[1],
        text: opt[0]
      }).appendTo(optgroup)                                // append option to group
    })        
    optgroup.appendTo(slct)                                // append group to select
  })
}

change(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="task_id"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is your complete code in the function, but you are not creating an optgroup

```js
var data = {
  "01 CONSULT": [
    ["1b Rules", "40"]
  ],
  "02 DEVELOPMENT": [],
  "03 QUALITY": [],
  "05 MARKETING": [
    ["5e Research", "66"]
  ],
  "06 MISCELLANEOUS": [
    ["6a Training", "69"],
    ["6b Meetings", "70"]
  ]
};




change();

function change() {
  var $select = $('#task_id');
  for (d in data) {
    var parent = d;
    var children = data[d];
    console.log(d);
    var $optgroup = $('<optgroup/>', {
      label: d,
    }).appendTo($select);
    for (c in children) {
      var child = data[d][c];
      $('<option/>', {
        value: child,
        html: child
      }).appendTo($optgroup);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="task_id">
</select>
```